# How do I fetch the latest transaction without using Zero MQ stream on a specific address?

Tags: address, javascript, development

When I make a simple request like shown in the iota workshop: https://github.com/iota-community/javascript-iota-workshop - 2.2-fetch-hello.js
the newest transaction is not fetched but a random one. How can I fetch the newest transaction?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't click the link to the workshop. The way I would do it is to use the `getTips` api call. This will return all tips including old stale one.

However, by examining the IRI code we can see that we have FIFO list that keeps the tips, so I believe that the first one will be the newest transaction...

Note that if the node tries to solidify a path, then the newest transaction the node receives may not necessarily be a tip.